# How to pass array of long to ASP.NET Core Controller POST method via AngularJS http.post

Tags: angularjs, arrays, post, asp.net-core

I merge two arrays in my AngularJS controller and sent it via http.post:

```
var selectedIds = angular.extend({}, $scope.selectedFirstKeys, $scope.selectedSecondKeys);
            $http.post("/api/tests/test/1", selectedIds )
                .then(function (response) {
                    ...                    
            });
```

With Fiddler I see the array is sent like this:

```
{"0":22}
```

But when I define my POST method like this it doesn't recognize the array:

```
[HttpPost("test/{testId:long}")]
    public IActionResult Test(long testId, [FromBody] long[] selectedIds)
    {
        ...
    }
```

How do I define the Controller method so it recognizes the array?

Comment: `{"0":22}` isn't really an array, it an object. Arrays are in square brackets `[0,22,...]`. Are you sure that what you are passing is correct?

Comment: That is what the angular.extend method created for me. And the data is correct. An array with one item (22)

Comment: Are `$scope.selectedFirstKeys` and  `$scope.selectedSecondKeys` arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into consideration that what you want to pass to your backend logic is an array.

This code is **wrong**

```
var selectedIds = angular.extend({}, $scope.selectedFirstKeys, $scope.selectedSecondKeys);
```

- *Because*: it copies the content of `$scope.selectedFirstKeys,` and `$scope.selectedSecondKeys` into **`{}`** (which is an object!), so the final result will be an object too! **:(**

The **correct** way (Assuming that `$scope.selectedSecondKeys` and `$scope.selectedSecondKeys` are arrays) is:

```
$scope.selectedFirstKeys = $scope.selectedFirstKeys.concat($scope.selectedSecondKeys);
```

- *Because*: it set `$scope.selectedFirstKeys` with the result of cancatenating `$scope.selectedFirstKeys` and `$scope.selectedSecondKeys`, which will be an array too! **:)**

---

You might want to see additional info about [Array.prototype.concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k55b14b3(v=vs.100).aspx) (and on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975170/javascript-how-to-join-combine-two-arrays-to-concatenate-into-one-array)) and [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) (and on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827866/angularjs-copy-vs-extend)). An extract is shown below:

---

**`Array.prototype.concat`**

> The concat() method returns a new array comprised of the array on
>   which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided
>   as arguments.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `var new_array = old_array.concat(value1[, value2[, ...[, valueN]]])`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `valueN`: Arrays and/or values to concatenate into a new array.

---

**`angular.extend`**

> Extends the destination object `dst` by copying own enumerable
>   properties from the `src` object(s) to `dst`.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `angular.extend(dst, src);`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `dst`: Destination object
>
> `src`: Source object(s)